# Border between materials

Tags: materials

[image]
I have two materials here and i want to mix them to have a smooth border between them.(but not just put them one after another like layers). Explain me please how to do it.

Comment: you have to use a gradient as a stencil, or as a mix node factor if ur using cycles.

Comment: You cant do it using two different materials, but you can mix it with a mask inside one material. Also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8002/how-can-the-demarcation-between-two-materials-be-smoothed or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49914/smooth-transition-between-2-materials